# 'expecting EOS' under the conditional statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

MS SQL Server tells me 'expecting EOS' under the conditional statement starting from CASE.
Can somebody figure out what is wrong with this code?

---

```
SELECT 
    goal,
    AVG(pledged) AS avg_num_pledged, 
    AVG(backers) AS avg_num_backers


CASE WHEN currency='GBP' THEN goal*1.3

ELSEIF =currency ='CAD' THEN goal*0.76

ELSEIF currency ='AUD' THEN goal*0.71

ELSEIF currency ='NOK' THEN goal*0.11

ELSEIF currency ='EUR' THEN goal*1.18

ELSEIF currency ='MXN' THEN goal*0.048

ELSEIF currency='SEK' THEN goal*0.11

ELSEIF currency='NZD' THEN goal*0.67

ELSEIF currency='CHF' THEN goal*1.11

ELSEIF currency='DKK' THEN goal*0.16

ELSEIF currency='HKD' THEN goal*0.13

ELSEIF currency='SGD' THEN goal*0.74
ELSEIF currency='JPY' THEN goal*0.0095

ELSE goal

END AS currency_uniformed



FROM kickstarter;
```

Comment: Syntax is `CASE WHEN [condition] THEN [expression] {ELSE expression} END`

Comment: Your exchange rates should be in a separate table, not hardcoded into a query.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments earlier, the `CASE` syntax is incorrect. You can also move the multiplication outside the `CASE` expression. To get a runnable query there is also a `grouping` clause missing to handle the aggregation (`AVG()`) across the `goal` column.

```
SELECT goal,
       AVG(
       case currency
          when 'GBP' then 1.3
          when 'CAD' then 0.76
          when 'AUD' then 0.71
          ...
          else 1
        end * goal) AS goal_currency_uniformed,
       AVG(pledged) AS avg_num_pledged, 
       AVG(backers) AS avg_num_backers
FROM kickstarter
GROUP BY goal;
```

Please consider moving the exchange rates to a separate table. This will allow you to slim this query down a bit and has the additional advantage that you can update the exchange rates without reworking your code.

```
SELECT ks.goal,
       AVG(er.rate * ks.goal) as goal_currency_uniformed,
       AVG(pledged) AS avg_num_pledged, 
       AVG(backers) AS avg_num_backers
FROM kickstarter ks
JOIN exchangerates er ON er.currency = ks.currency
GROUP BY goal;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=147e9cc3c73e102ec76b1e68aa5acc97) to see everything in action.

Comment: You are welcome! If this completes your question then you could formally "accept" the answer to remove your question from the big pile of "unaswered questions".